# Loading a select box options on the basis of other select box using jsonSchema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm using jsonschema to generate our forms and validate these.

Below is a sample json:

```
{
  "title": "Microsoft Account Request",
  "readOnly": false,
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema",
  "description": "Microsoft Azure Account Request Product Specification",
  "properties": {
    "product": {
      "title": "Product",
      "dataBinding": {"references": ["SPEC_ID#/properties/service"]},
      "properties": {
        "offers": {
          "title": "Product Offers",
          "propertyOrder": 1,
          "type": "array",
          "uniqueItems": true,
          "format": "tabs",
          "items": {
            "title":"Product Offer",
            "properties": {
              "category": {
                "title": "Category",
                "readOnly": false,
                "unique":true,
                "strictProperties": true,
                "enum": [
                  "Cloud Services",
                  "Virtual Machines",
                  "Azure App Service",
                  "Batch"


                ],
                "options": {
                    "dependencies": [
                      {"id":"subcategoryAdd", "value":true}
                    ]
                  },
                "description": "Select category",
                "propertyOrder": 1,
                "type": "string"
              },
              "subcategory": {
                  "id":"subcategoryAdd",
                "title": "Sub - Category",
                "readOnly": false,
                "strictProperties": true,
                "description": "Select Sub-Category",
                 "options": {
                    "hide_display": true
                  },
                "enum": [
                  "Build and Deployment",
                  "Application Insights"
                ],
                "propertyOrder": 2,
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "type": "object"
          }
        }

      },
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

And sample output:

[image]

In the output form, I have highlighted the sub-category option in it's select box should be loaded on the basis of selected category.

For example, if I select `batch` then subcategory options a,b,c should be shown in select box for subcategory and if I select `Azure app service` then subcategory options d,e,f should be shown in select box for subcategory.

I was trying it with `dependencies` but in vain. Also, I tried to accomplish this by using `watch` and `enumSource` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor)

Any helps would be worth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your category/subcategory relationship can be validated using the following JSON Schema.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "category": { "enum": ["foo"] },
        "subCategory": { "enum": ["asdf", "jkl;"] }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "category": { "enum": ["bar"] },
        "subCategory": { "enum": ["asdf", "qwer", "uiop"] }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this doesn't mean the form generator you are using will be able to create a form based on this.  I'd be impressed if it can.